# Truncate 64 bit value to 32 bit value without UB

Tags: c, c99

Does this simple code snippet have fully defined behavior by C99 standard?

```
{
  uint64_t longer = 0x122223333u;
  uint32_t shorter = longer;
  assert(shorter == 0x22223333u);
}
```

If not, what is a standard-compliant way to achieve this (put lower 32 bits of a `uint64_t` value to a `uint32_t` variable)?

Comment: You could overlay the two types in a `union`.

Comment: @Bathsheba pretty sure that'd definitely be UB.

Comment: Really? A union with one uint64_t and two consecutive uint32_t?

Comment: A union would rely on the memory layout, so it should be UB IMO. After all, it doesn't take into account the ordering of the bytes.

Comment: @Devolus Type-punning through a union gives implementation-defined results (that can produce trap values depending on the implementation) according to footnote 82 in C99TC3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The draft C99 standard says:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.

So, in this case the 64-bit value would be converted by repeatedly subtracting `0x1_0000_0000` from it until the result fits in 32 bits (underscores added for readability).

In your case, after one such subtraction the result is `0x22223333`. It seems pretty clear that it can be proven that this is the same thing as just doing the truncation, I really don't think actual subtractions ever happen.

Answer (score 4):

Unsigned integral types obey the rules of modular arithmetic without any undefined behaviour, so the assignment is perfectly valid and correct.

More than that, the optionally-available types `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` actually guarantee to have no padding and be exactly 32 or 64 bits wide, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Unsigned truncation is well defined to be modulo `2^n`. It's the signed truncation which is tricky and less defined.

So yes, this is defined and the assert is true, regardless of the endianness of the machine.